# Is there anything about ext js?

Tags: extjs

I need a project about it ,thank you.I am using Ext.grid.gridpanel.As in rowclick event, we can handle row click of grid..Is there any event to handle column click of grid?

i want to select a particular column of grid.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for headerclick. Also for any more questions like this just look through the extjs documentation per your version. Sencha documents it very well.